# jquery get listbox value when hovered over it

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am tryinh to get the value of my selected list box when I hover over it. The below code works well in google crome but does not work in internet explorer. Is there a way to get this working in IE.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#ListBox1 option").hover(
        function (e) {
            var a = this.value;
            alert(a);

        });
     });
</script>

<select name="drop1" id="ListBox1" size="4" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
    <option value="4">item 4</option>
    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>
```

Comment: You probably want `mouseenter`, not `hover`, in this case. [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) attaches an event handler to *both* [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) **and** [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Hmm, do you want it to alert when you are over the selected option, or when you are over any part of the list box?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the jQuery wrapper on the select list, that might remove the browser specific problems -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#ListBox1 option").hover(
    function (e) {
        var a = $(this).val();
        alert(a);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :selected to alert when over the selected item

```
$("#ListBox1 option:selected").hover( function () {  alert(); });
```